# Javascript Based Story Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to build a website with a story based flow using Javascript and jQuery to manage the 'flow' of the story. The best way to describe what I'm looking to do is with [an example](http://www.theguardian.com/global-development/ng-interactive/2014/jan/refugee-choices-interactive).

In this example they use an Ajax loader plugin called [Lazyload](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload) to load assets from another JS file (Looks like underscore.js formatted, maybe?). It looks like a very complicated way of achieving something that should be easier, though, IMO.

As a starting point, all elements could be on the page and hidden with `.(hide)`, the click of each button would reveal and scroll to the relevant item, a class would then be added to that button to make them greyed out and unclickable. Or maybe use Ajax to call in story components as they are needed? What do you think is the simplest and best way of doing this?

Comment: If your story is going to be very long and if you would also include high resolution pictures and videos like in the example, then you have a lot of data to be loaded if you would use the non-ajax-idea. So i would say it depends on the amount of data, whether you should reload inbetween.

Comment: Hi Martin, yes you're right it does depend on the content. From a JS POV, how would you go about coding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According you want to use the long-story-version:

Well my very first idea of how this could work was to store each StoryPart (lets call it Item) in a special File which you can load with ajax later.

Then it would be possible to define a possible storyPath where you can use itemId's.

Does this help you?

Comment: Yes you're right. I agree that's probably the best way for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the amount of data you need to load, I would do this:

1. Load the page normally (without the story)
2. Display some kind of loading/waiting interface to the user while requesting the whole story by ajax call
3. Show only the first item after ajax completes
4. Hide the "wait" interface from the page

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that seems like the best way to go.